# Is there a way to use foreach loop to assign values row-wise to a column based on other numeric column within one dataframe?

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, rvest

[image]I have a dataframe with two columns, one numeric and other character column

I have almost 300 rows with  numbers and url links

Based on the numeric column, I want to loop through each url from 1 to number of times the value in num for each row

**I tried using this code :**

```
sites <- for (i in 1:df$v1) {
foreach (n = i, .combine = cbind) %dopar% {data.frame( paste(df$url, n,sep= ""))}}
```

But, this code takes only the first numeric value and repeats through all urls instead of taking row-wise numeric values

**I expect this :**

```
https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page1
https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page2

And so on ...

https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page14
https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page1
https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page2

And so on ...

https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page5
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a little unclear for me. "Based on the numeric column, I want to loop through each url from 1 to number of times the value in num for each row". What function or operation are you applying in the loop? And I think you mean loop through a vector of urls and not loop through each url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop over each row one way using `sapply`

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) paste0(df$url[i], seq_len(df$V1[i])))

#[[1]]
# [1] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page1" 
# [2] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page2" 
# [3] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page3" 
# [4] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page4" 
# [5] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page5" 
# [6] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page6" 
# [7] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page7" 
# [8] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page8" 
# [9] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page9" 
#[10] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page10"
#[11] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page11"
#[12] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page12"
#[13] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page13"
#[14] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page14"

#[[2]]
#[1] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page1"
#[2] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page2"
#[3] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page3"
#[4] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page4"
#[5] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page5"
```

This gives you a list of character vector but instead of that if you want everything as one vector only you could `unlist` the `sapply` call

```
unlist(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) paste0(df$url[i], seq_len(df$V1[i]))))
```

Assuming your initial data is something like this :

```
df<- data.frame(url=c(
 "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page", 
 "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page"), 
               V1 = c(14, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `rep` and `sequence` from `base R`

```
with(df, paste0(rep(url, V1), sequence(V1)))
# [1] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page1"     
# [2] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page2"     
# [3] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page3"     
# [4] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page4"     
# [5] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page5"     
# [6] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page6"     
# [7] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page7"     
# [8] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page8"     
# [9] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page9"     
#[10] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page10"    
#[11] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page11"    
#[12] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page12"    
#[13] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page13"    
#[14] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page14"    
#[15] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page1"
#[16] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page2"
#[17] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page3"
#[18] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page4"
#[19] "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page5"
```

---

Or using the `foreach`

```
library(foreach)
out <- foreach(i = seq_len(nrow(df)), .combine = rbind) %dopar% 
           data.frame(Col1 = paste0(df$url[i], seq(df$V1[i])))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(url = structure(2:1, 
.Label = c("https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8943521-Larger-tires/page", 
  "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?9147410-Durango/page"
 ), class = "factor"), V1 = c(14, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```